# RabbitMQ in Docker Swarm: Discover task instances by hostname

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, docker-swarm, service-discovery

I have a RabbitMQ cluster running in Swarm, configured as a global service, which has the hostname set to the host's name:

```yaml
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbitmq-{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    networks:
      - rabbitmq
    configs:
      - source: rabbitmq_config
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    secrets:
      - source: rabbitmq_erlang_cookie
        target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_NODENAME: "rabbit@rabbitmq-{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

The nodes all receive a dynamically generated [configuration file with all the nodes in it](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#peer-discovery-classic-config), so they can form the cluster:

```ini
docker_hosts=$(docker node ls --format '{{.Hostname}}')
count=0
for host in ${docker_hosts}; do
  count=$((count+1))
  echo "cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.${count} = rabbit@rabbitmq-${host}" >> rabbitmq.conf
done
```

I would like to replace this classic discovery configuration with the [DNS peer discovery backend](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#peer-discovery-dns) to discover the other tasks automatically, but hit some road blocks.

The built-in Docker DNS daemon allows to [discover tasks](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#container-discovery) by doing a query for `tasks.<service name>`. For RabbitMQ, this yields output like:

```yaml
root@rabbitmq-foo-1:/# nslookup tasks.rabbitmq
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   tasks.rabbitmq
Address: 10.100.8.158
Name:   tasks.rabbitmq
Address: 10.100.8.162
Name:   tasks.rabbitmq
Address: 10.100.8.163
```

This means we can pass the seed hostname `tasks.rabbitmq` to RabbitMQ, and it will perform an A lookup during startup. As per the documentation, the result to this query will *"append [the] current node's prefix (e.g. rabbit in rabbit@hostname1.example.local) to each hostname and return the result."*
Performing a manual reverse lookup, we get results like the following:

```ini
root@rabbitmq-foo-1:/# nslookup 10.100.8.158
158.8.100.10.in-addr.arpa   name = foo_rabbitmq.tjqxe6kpe5g4mnmgwoiuink16.xhosndlwm3eaoldu36udvjfi9.rabbitmq-net.
```

This means the Docker DNS service builds reverse records as:

```
<Project Name>_<Task Name>.<Task ID>.< Container ID>.<Network Name>.
```

Unfortunately, RabbitMQ doesn't work well with that name: Even if configured to [use the FQDN for nodes](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cli.html#node-names), RabbitMQ will **check the resolved RR record against the node's hostname and only join the cluster if they match**.

So instead of `foo_rabbitmq.tjqxe6kpe5g4mnmgwoiuink16.xhosndlwm3eaoldu36udvjfi9.rabbitmq-net.`, it needs `rabbitmq-foo-1.whatever.` (where the host is named `foo-1`.)

Is there a way to resolve the given hostname of the task instances instead? Or a DNS endpoint to get all Swarm nodes?

Comment: the reverse record will be {container name}.{network name}. for services, the container name is a combo of {task name}.{task id}. I can't think of any particular way to make this comply with RabbitMQs expectations :/

Comment: This is probably a job for a new discovery backend in RabbitMQ - if only I knew Erlang...

Comment: I have the feeling that you could work around that by running rabbitMq containers in host network mode paired with the ability to register all the docker nodes on the same DNS record

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich I saw your gist and made a comment requesting to view your config and definitions file, please share when you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I moved RabbitMQ to a Docker Swarm Cluster just last week and had exactly the same problem.

These are the key properties:

- Creating a custom internal network with custom name to have a deterministic network name
- Setting container hostname to '{{.Task.Name}}.$NETWORK_NAME' (see docker-compose.yml) - this will fix the reverse DNS name matching problem
- Setting env var RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME=true
- Setting deploy->endpoint_mode to "dnsrr" to allow DNS discovery of all replicas by service name
- Configure DNS cluster formation in RabbitMQ config file

### Here is my full solution for DNS Discovery of RabbitMQ in Docker Swarm:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    # utilize HAProxy as proxy server in front of all rabbits
    rabbit-haproxy:
        image: haproxy
        ports:
            - 5672:5672
            - 7000:7000
            - 8071:8071
        networks:
            - external-rabbit
            - rabbit-internal
        configs:
            - source: haproxy-config
              target: /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

    rabbit:
        image: rabbitmq:3.11-management-alpine
        # set hostname to the final combination of reverse DNS name
        hostname: '{{.Task.Name}}.rabbits'
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME=true
            - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/config/rabbitmq
        configs:
            - source: rabbit-config
              target: /config/rabbitmq
        secrets:
            - source: rabbit-erlang-cookie
              target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
              mode: 0600
              gid: "101"
              uid: "100"
        networks:
            - rabbit-internal
        deploy:
            endpoint_mode: dnsrr

configs:
    haproxy-config:
        file: config/haproxy.cfg
    rabbit-config:
        file: config/rabbit

secrets:
    rabbit-erlang-cookie:
        file: config/rabbit-erlang-cookie

networks:
    rabbit-internal:
        name: rabbits
        driver: overlay
    external-rabbit:
    external: true
```

RabbitMQ config file ("config/rabbit")

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_dns
cluster_formation.dns.hostname = rabbit
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_limit = 10
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_interval = 1000
```

HAProxy excerpt ("config/haproxy.cfg")

```
listen rabbitmq
bind 0.0.0.0:5672
mode tcp
option tcpka
balance roundrobin
server-template rabbit- 1-9 rabbit:5672 check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none
```

RabbitMQ Erlang Cookie file ("config/rabbit-erlang-cookie")

```
mysupersecreterlangcookie---changeme
```

### Caveat:

When RabbitMQ is in auto discovery mode, it tries to discover a RabbitMQ cluster that *is already running*. Cluster formation will take place when a single rabbit thinks, he is alone and needs to start a standalone cluster.

So when first initialized, there will be no clusters present. Starting 2 oder more rabbit replicas will cause them to try to find each other, eventually all failing due to parallelism and thus creating their separate clusters.

Start with one replica and then scale up the cluster as needed. This way you can be sure there is a cluster present that can be discovered by new peer nodes.

Comment: Woah, that's a neat solution to the DNS discovery issue! I can help with the cluster bootstrapping, I think: We solved this by using a combination of health checks and update conditions. Take a look at my config here: https://gist.github.com/Radiergummi/aa6e2d9a7d50afe626f776ed1d6b97e1

Comment: You mean by utilizing a combination of deploy->update_config->parallelism and healthcheck? I tried doing it without healthcheck and parallelism set to 1, but it was starting all replicas at once.. maybe this was because of a missing healthcheck or because you deployed globally vs. num of replicas. I will give it another try, thanks for the hint!

Comment: So at least for replica mode, this does not seem like a solution to prevent single-cluster formation, unfortunately. I added `healthcheck` (with lower threshold values) and deploy config with `monitor: 10`, `order: stop-first` and `parallelism: 1` but new containers will always be started all at once. Will check with `mode: global` later once I have more time for this.